# Copying latest files from the remote servers

Tags: bash, shell-script, scp

We run report on multiple remote servers which we pick up monthly on our central server. The whole process is automated with `scp` and working well.

The issue is that sometimes we go on individual servers and try to run these reports manually to gather data and that creates the issue.  This way our central server get many files from the same server which we have to find and delete.

I am looking for ideas as to how we can make this process smart so we don't have to deal with multiple files from the same server for the current month.

Answer (score 0):

> the issue is that sometimes we go on individual servers and try to run
>   these reports manually to gather data and that creates the issue. This
>   way our central server get many files from the same server which we
>   have to find and delete.

By the above statement, I understand that you need to keep only one copy of the remote server file in your central server. You can achieve it by Keeping only one copy of the file from the remote servers.

To achieve it, you can append the remote server names along with the timestamp to all the files while doing the scp operation. So, if a newer file appears for the central server you can overwrite the older file with the file that has the newest timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Couple options:

Separate the one-off manual running of the report that is generated so that manual runs are stored elsewhere and your automatic monthly reports always contain just the monthly report.

or

Have the script that generates the report accept an optional parameter so that you can call the monthly report from cron with the applicable month so the filename is then something like 'current-report.June', etc. As manual runs will not contain the special parameter, your process that grabs the monthly report will be able to grab just that months report (naturally this example is limited, you will likely want to have month and year so that you do not run into issues if you decide to keep more than 12 months of data).

And like the above, I'm sure there are infinite variations on the above. I personally prefer keeping automated scripts/reports separate from ad-hoc ones, but that does of course mean double maintenance if a change is needed. So it may be best to allow for the flexibility of parameters added to your report generator to not break your monthly process when someone runs an ad-hoc report.